# Как поставить loader

Tags: javascript

Запустил loader - пустил Ajax запрос к серверу - пришел ответ - остановил loader.
Kак это можно сделать?

Comment: какой loader?

Comment: прогресс бар

Comment: Вам принципиально на чистом javascript-е? Есть возможность использовать библиотеку jQuery?

Comment: есть, но у меня нет понятия на какое событие его ставить
если я напишу что-то вроде этого:
Ajax-query(который возвращает name)
if(name){
alert(true);
}, тогда алерт выполнится раньше чем пришел запрос

Comment: >если я напишу что-то вроде этого: Ajax-query(который возвращает name) if(name){ alert(true); }, тогда алерт выполнится раньше чем пришел запрос

ajax - это это **asynchronous javascript and xml**. Ключевое слово в данном случае - **асинхронный**/ Используйте коллбэки

Comment: я над этим задумывался
но если после этого запроса у меня должно быть еще много функций ?
Корректно ли буде воспользоваться callback?

Comment: Если на чистом XHR, то нужно перед send запустить прогресс-бар, а в реализации onreadystatechange остановить его.  
Как пользоваться XHR можно посмотреть здесь например:  
http://xmlhttprequest.ru/  
(оказывается целый сайт есть об этом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грубо говоря так:

```
<img class="loader" style="display: none;" src="/img/loader.gif">

<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('img.loader').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('img.loader').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: спасибо
а как сделать чтобы функция , которую я напишу после ajax-запроса, выполнялась только после того , когда придет ответ с сервера?

Comment: немного отойду от темы, как в JavaScript сделать так ,чтобы следующая функция выполнялась после завершения первой?

Comment: @hil400k callback

    function callbacker(callback)
    {
        callback.apply(this);
    }

Comment: @hil400k, добавьте свою функцию:

    complete: function() {
        $('img.loader').hide();
        // сюда
    }